# Подключение компилятора Java/Kotlin к приложению

Tags: android, компилятор

Как прикрутить компилятор к android приложению, с целью отладки кода непосредственно на смартфоне?

Comment: Лайков не будет, так как вопрос слишком общий и по формату не подходит для ruSO

Comment: вопрос действительно теоретический, поэтому требуется помощь масс, если бы я мог его хоть как-то конкретизировать, я бы это сделал

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev ни лайки, ни массы вам не помогут.

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev, тем более не поможет такой комментарий (наезд)...

Comment: @GeorgiyChebotarev не для однотипных, а для небольших и конкретных. Ваш вопрос большой и неконкретный и не соответствует тематике сайта. А ещё на «как сделать юзабельным» нельзя ответить однозначно и объективно (то, что одним людям удобно, другим будет неудобно), и это тоже не соответствует тематике сайта, такие дела

Comment: так достаточно конкретно и локанично?

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Что именно вы собрались отлаживать непосредственно на смартфоне?

Comment: @rjhdby, человеку нужно аналог AIDE для котлина написать

Comment: так точно! Нужен аналог AIDE, но развернутый вопрос получился не конкретным, поэтому я конкретизировал его на одном аспекте: есть ли возможность добавить компилятор в приложение, и если есть то как это сделать граммотнее всего